# Saving the Wordpress header to a php file accessible anywhere?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I have been searching all day to figure this out and still cant find an answer. I want to take the header of my wordpress site and have its own file (headerstandalone.php). I want it to do all the functions and calling it needs to do without being in the same directory as the standard header.php. Is this possible?

I am basically trying to implement it into some custom pages.

Comment: Why don't you use header-{slug}.php & call it using get_header(slug)

Comment: I am trying to incorporate it into a MyBB forum. However I can retrieve it through MyBB like that. However I can take and retrieve a file that retrieves the header. Header -> Middle File -> MyBB.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help you with your problem?

```
<?php include_once("headerstandalone.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the headerstandalone.php in a seperate directory,  be sure to include wp-load.php in your standalone file so you can use all your functions and then include that file in your main header using require_once(../another_directory/headerstandalone.php).

If you don't want to include the file in you header then you could add the standaloneheader.php code to a function and add it to either your own plugin's function file or the themes function file and call that function in the header.